# How can I install and use OBLogout?

Tags: desktop-environments, logout, openbox

> OBLogout is a expandable, configurable, and theme-able logout script designed to be used in a Openbox desktop environment.

This was taken from [their Launchpad page](https://launchpad.net/oblogout), it was created to be used in Crunchabng Linux and I can find packages for Arch, Fedora and Debian but no information on how to Install it in Ubuntu, I can't find it in the repositories either and the only [PPA](https://launchpad.net/~nikdoof/+archive/ppa) is 3 years old.

How can I install it and is there a possibility that it could work in other environments other than Openbox?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The version 0.2 of oblogout in the PPA appears to be the latest version. Therefore, I would say that would be the one to try. It is over 3 years old but I don't believe that Openbox has seen any major developments that would break it. Additionally, I have seen articles and forum posts from this year that indicate that it is still being used on current distros.